# Reply-To field not showing on openerp v7

Tags: odoo

How can I show the **reply-to** field when a message is send to an email address? I'm confused because sometimes it shows, sometimes not..

I used Openerp v7..

I modify the **_get_default_from** from **mail_mail.py**.

```
def _get_default_from(self, cr,uid, context=None):
this = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid,uid, context=context)
    if this.alias_domain:
    return '%s@%s' % (this.alias_name,this.alias_domain)
elif this.email:
    return this.email
    raise osv.except_osv(_('Invalid Action!'), _("Unable to send email, please configure the sender's email address or alias."))
_defaults = {
    'state': 'outgoing',
    'email_from': lambda self, cr, uid, ctx=None: self._get_default_from(cr, uid,ctx),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously `_get_default_from()` method is used for getting a value for 'email_from' field.

See the *_columns* in **mail_mail.py**, there is a column that is called 'reply_to':

```
'reply_to': fields.char('Reply-To', help='Preferred response address for the message')
```

If you want to show 'reply_to', I think you will have to add this field to the XML files, where the views are defined.